# How could I make FFTW Hilbert transform calculate faster?

Tags: c++, performance, signal-processing

I'm using the Hilbert transform function from the FFTW source. Because I am going to use it in my DAQ with data streaming mode. The function is working fine but the calculation speed is slow which will cause the FIFO overflow. I've heard that move the `fftw_plan()` outside from the `hilbert()` for reuse the `plan` might be useful, however, it's an error once I did that, saying `Exception thrown at 0x0000000070769240 (libfftw3-3.dll) in CppFFTW.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000. at the fftw_destroy_plan(plan);`. Does anyone has similar experiences or even better solution to boost up the `hilbert()` calculation?

Here is what I've tried (2020 12/30 edited):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;

//macros for real and imaginary parts
#define REAL 0
#define IMAG 1
//length of complex array
#define N 8



void hilbert(const double* in, fftw_complex* out, fftw_plan plan_forward, fftw_plan plan_backward)
{
    // copy the data to the complex array
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] = in[i];
        out[i][IMAG] = 0;
    }
    // creat a DFT plan and execute it
    //fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan_forward);
    // destroy a plan to prevent memory leak
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan_forward);
    int hN = N >> 1; // half of the length (N/2)
    int numRem = hN; // the number of remaining elements
    // multiply the appropriate value by 2
    //(those should multiplied by 1 are left intact because they wouldn't change)
    for (int i = 1; i < hN; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] *= 2;
        out[i][IMAG] *= 2;
    }
    // if the length is even, the number of the remaining elements decrease by 1
    if (N % 2 == 0)
        numRem--;
    else if (N > 1) {
        out[hN][REAL] *= 2;
        out[hN][IMAG] *= 2;
    }
    // set the remaining value to 0
    // (multiplying by 0 gives 0, so we don't care about the multiplicands)
    memset(&out[hN + 1][REAL], 0, numRem * sizeof(fftw_complex));
    // creat a IDFT plan and execute it
    //plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan_backward);
    // do some cleaning
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan_backward);
    //fftw_cleanup();
    // scale the IDFT output
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] /= N;
        out[i][IMAG] /= N;
    }








}
/* Displays complex numbers in the form a +/- bi. */
void displayComplex(fftw_complex* y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (y[i][IMAG] < 0)
            cout << y[i][REAL] << "-" << abs(y[i][IMAG]) << "i" << endl;
        else
            cout << y[i][REAL] << "+" << y[i][IMAG] << "i" << endl;
    }
}



/* Test */
int main()
{
    // input array
    double x[N];
    // output array
    fftw_complex y[N];
    fftw_plan plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, y, y, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
   
    fftw_plan plan_backward = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, y, y, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    



   
    // fill the first of some numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        x[i] = i + 1;  // i.e.{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8}
    }
    // compute the FFT of x and store the result in y.
    hilbert(x, y, plan_forward, plan_backward);
    // display the result
    cout << "Hilbert =" << endl;
    displayComplex(y);
   
}
```

The exact output value

```
Hilbert =
1+3.82843i
2-1i
3-1i
4-1.82843i
5-1.82843i
6-1i
7-1i
8+3.82843i
```

Here is the original code:

````
#include <iostream>
#include <fftw3.h>


using namespace std;

//macros for real and imaginary parts
#define REAL 0
#define IMAG 1
//length of complex array
#define N 8

void hilbert(const double* in, fftw_complex* out)
{
    // copy the data to the complex array
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] = in[i];
        out[i][IMAG] = 0;
    }
    // creat a DFT plan and execute it
    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan);
    // destroy a plan to prevent memory leak
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
    int hN = N >> 1; // half of the length (N/2)
    int numRem = hN; // the number of remaining elements
    // multiply the appropriate value by 2
    //(those should multiplied by 1 are left intact because they wouldn't change)
    for (int i = 1; i < hN; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] *= 2;
        out[i][IMAG] *= 2;
    }
    // if the length is even, the number of the remaining elements decrease by 1
    if (N % 2 == 0)
        numRem--;
    else if (N > 1) {
        out[hN][REAL] *= 2;
        out[hN][IMAG] *= 2;
    }
    // set the remaining value to 0
    // (multiplying by 0 gives 0, so we don't care about the multiplicands)
    memset(&out[hN + 1][REAL], 0, numRem * sizeof(fftw_complex));
    // creat a IDFT plan and execute it
    plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan);
    // do some cleaning
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
    fftw_cleanup();
    // scale the IDFT output
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] /= N;
        out[i][IMAG] /= N;
    }



   




}
/* Displays complex numbers in the form a +/- bi. */
void displayComplex(fftw_complex* y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (y[i][IMAG] < 0)
            cout << y[i][REAL] << "-" << abs(y[i][IMAG]) << "i" << endl;
        else
            cout << y[i][REAL] << "+" << y[i][IMAG] << "i" << endl;
    }
}



/* Test */
int main()
{
    
 
    // input array
    double x[N];
    // output array
    fftw_complex y[N];
    // fill the first of some numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        x[i] = i + 1;  // i.e.{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8}
    }
    // compute the FFT of x and store the result in y.
    hilbert(x, y);
    // display the result
    cout << "Hilbert =" << endl;
    displayComplex(y);
 
}
```
````

Comment: Post only the working code, remove any mention of throwing exceptions. Change the `C` tag to C++ because @chux-ReinstateMonica is correct, this is C++ code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Updated Code Review for 2020-12-30 Code

Some of the original code review items have been addressed. Good work! Here are some remaining ideas:

- I assume your purpose here is to make the `hilbert` function faster, because you will call it multiple times. You've moved the FFT plan creation outside of `hilbert`, which is probably a huge speed increase. However, you still call `fftw_destroy_plan` within `hilbert`. This is a problem if you call `hilbert` more than once. You should move `fftw_destroy_plan` outside of `hilbert`, so it would be called from `main` instead.
- You have three different `for` loops inside `hilbert`. One copies data from input vector to output vector. One scales half the output vector by a factor of 2. One scales the output vector by 1/N. These loops can all be combined into a single loop at the beginning of `hilbert`. This works because an FFT is linear, so scaling the input by a constant factor is the same as scaling the output by a constant factor. This new loop would look something like:

  ```
      auto scale = 2.0 / N;
      for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
      {
          out[i][REAL] = in[i] * scale;
          out[i][IMAG] = 0.0;
      }
  ```

  Then you would get rid of the other `for` loops. You would also get rid of the code which multiplies out[hN] by 2 (but keep the call to `memset` which zeros the second half of the output). Finally, you need to fix out[0], which is now too large by a factor of two:

  ```
      out[0][REAL] /= 2.0;
      out[0][IMAG] /= 2.0;
  ```

  However, the speed increase from combining these loops is probably small compared to the FFT time.
- It may take a little more work, but you could change the forward FFT so that it takes its input directly from the real-valued input vector. This is probably close to twice as fast as the complex FFT you are currently doing (but this is just for the forward FFT, so your overall speed increase might be up to 25%). Still, I think it is likely that your complex FFT is already fast enough now that you've removed the creation/destruction of the plan outside of `hilbert`.

### Original Code Review for Original 2020-12-26 Code

- In general, using global variables is a bad idea (see below for my reasoning for this statement). You declare a global variable `out`. It is never used, because your `hilbert` function takes a parameter named `out`. So just delete the global `out` variable.
- You also declare the FFT plan as a global variable. This `plan` is what gets used by the `hilbert` function. But when you initialize the plan in `main`, you declare a local `plan` variable. The local `plan` variable gets initialized by `fft_plan_dft_1d`, but that doesn't initialize the global variable. The local `plan` variable is never used. Better would be to get rid of the global `plan` variable, and use only the one declared in `main`. Pass it as a parameter into the `hilbert` function. (This may be one cause of your exception, since you're currently using an uninitialized plan variable inside `hilbert`.)
- You only have one `plan` variable, but it looks like you're trying to make it hold two plans. That won't work. It will remember only the last call to `fft_plan_dft_1d`, so both times you call `fft_execute`, you are getting an inverse FFT. And when you call `fft_destroy_plan` twice, the second one may cause an exception.

  To fix this, you'd want two different `plan` variables, maybe call them `plan_forward` and `plan_inverse` or something like that. Pass them both as parameters into the `hilbert` function.
- Having `using namespace std;` is generally not a good idea. Instead, when you want to use something from that namespace, put `std::` in front of the name. For example, use `std::cout` instead of `cout`.
- You have `int hN = N >> 1;`. I personally would prefer `int hN = N / 2`, as it seems clearer.
- You copy the input array into the output array and then do an in-place FFT. I think it should be possible to have fftw do a non-in-place FFT where the input vector is real-valued and the output is complex. This should be slightly more efficient. But I'm too lazy to look up the details of how to do it.

### Thoughts on Global Variables

My original review just said "In general, using global variables is a bad idea", without any explanation or context. Some of the comments on this answer either disagreed or wanted more explanation, so here's my reasoning.

As with most things related to coding style, reasonable people may have differing opinions. Furthermore, nothing is absolute, so I certainly acknowledge that there are cases where global variables are useful or even necessary. Perhaps I should have said "use global variables only when really necessary".

- What do commonly-used coding guidelines say?

  There are lots of coding guidelines on the internet. Many of them in some way discourage the use of global variables. Some examples:

  - The [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ri-global), maintained by Bjarne Stroustrup and Herb Sutter, say to avoid non-const global variables.
  - The [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Static_and_Global_Variables) forbids objects with static storage duration unless they are trivially destructable, and also discourages static storage duration if the object uses dynamic initialization. (Note: global variables have static storage duration.)
  - In [Joint Strike Fighter C++ Coding Standards](http://www.stroustrup.com/JSF-AV-rules.pdf), based on the MISRA C++ coding standards, AV Rule 98 says "Every nonlocal name, except main(), should be placed in some namespace." (This doesn't prohibit global variables, but does help avoid *some* of the problems caused by global variables.)
  - In [University of Michigan C++ Coding Standards](http://www.umich.edu/%7Eeecs381/handouts/C++_Coding_Standards.pdf), global variables are acceptable only in certain limited circumstances.
  - [Some random code guideline found on the internet](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-write-clean-code-in-c/) discourages use of global variables, suggesting that you instead use variables declared in functions.
- What can go wrong when you use global variables

  - Initialization issues. If global variables are declared in two different files, there is no specification of the order in which they are initialized. If the initialization of one of them depends on the value of the other, you have undefined behavior. It may appear to work sometimes, but it can't be relied upon.
  - Multi-thread issues. If multiple threads simultaneously try to use or modify a global variable, you can get unexpected or undefined behavior. Making this work correctly can be tricky, sometimes requiring the use of mutexes or similar constructs. Often, these constructs slow down the code substantially.
  - Name conflicts within a file. You can have a function-local variable and a global variable with the same name. They are different variables, and this can lead to confusion. Maybe you meant the local variable to access the global variable, but accidentally declared it locally. Or maybe you meant for the local variable to be different than the global variable, but a subsequent maintainer may not realize that and think they are the same variable. These kind of issues can lead to bugs.
  - Name conflicts with external libraries. If you have an external global variable, it can conflict with other external global variables with the same name. These kind of conflicts can make it difficult to integrate separate software libraries.

In many cases, global variables offer no benefit in exchange for the above potential problems (the original post is one example of that). Therefore, I think it is best to avoid global variables unless they are really necessary.

Comment: "In general, using global variables is a bad idea." is too sweeping a statement - global data is fine - it is an application dependent issue.  IAC unless that memory location affects performance, little reason to comment on it.

Comment: I still think that *in general* global variables are a bad idea, though I will admit there are times when they are useful/necessary.

Comment: Explain why in your experience global variables are bad. I happen to agree with you but in my answers I explain why.

Comment: The C++ Guidelines is a good reference for many things, including why one should [avoid non-const global variables](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ri-global)

Comment: I tried to follow your guide, but still several problems happened:
1. The VS is keep showing that `out` is an undefined variables, since I moved `fftw_plan plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);` out the `hilbert()`, so I still preserved `fftw_complex* out;` at global declaration, any better thoughts?
2. Similar to the `out` variable problem, as I moved `fftw_plan plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);` out `hilbert()`, the variable `plan` inside the `hilbert` became needs to be defined again.

Comment: In order to prevent the `plan` variables need to be defined, I moved both `fftw_execute` to the `main`. However, the code still didn't work since the similar `Exception thrown at 0x00000000707E4D38 (libfftw3-3.dll) in CppFFTW.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.` happened. Please take a look to the code I updated today at the question content.

Comment: A classic example where global data is good and allocated data is bad is with life critical applications (air traffic control, medical devices) where out-of-memory is simple not an option.  IAC, I see scant performance change (OP's review goals) due to its use or not.

Comment: @pacmaninbw OK, I've tried to add some explanation of why I think global variables are not generally a good idea.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, it is true that the global variables in the original post are not affecting performance, though they *were* contributing to a defect that prevents the code from working. Yes, embedded critical systems may be a place where allocated data is bad. However, even if the original post's hilbert transform was meant for that environment, I would still be arguing that the FFT plan variables should be passed into `hilbert` rather than be global.

Comment: "should be passed into hilbert" is an agreeable view and is more true with C++ than C (now that the tag has changed)  Yet   "using global variables is a bad idea" remains an overstatement and takes always from OP's efficiency  focus.

Comment: Better. Since the question is now closed you may not get a lot of up votes, but good job.

Comment: @Eric Backus I tried almost followed your instruction to rewrite the code, at least it can run normally now, but the output value was not right. Please take a look in the question content which I updated. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Kevin I think you've got some fundamental misunderstanding of C++ there. That's OK, we've all had to learn it at some point, and C++ is a complicated language. Anyway, you have no calls to FFT at all in your `hilbert` function, so all it is doing is multiplying the first half of the input data by 1/N (for the first point) or 2/N (for the remainder of the first half), and setting the second half of the points to zero. You need to put back the calls to `fft_execute` in `hilbert`, but leave the `plan_forward` and `plan_backward` in `main`.

Comment: Then pass `plan_forward` and `plan_backward` as parameters into `hilbert`, and use them in the calls to `fft_execute`. Your initialization of `plan_forward` and `plan_backward` should use `y`, not `out`, since `y` is what you pass to `hilbert`. Hope this helps... :)

Comment: @Eric Backus Thanks for the reply, I will try and realize what you mentioned above. In fact, I just be thrown to use C/C++ recently because our data stream DAQ card only support in C, since I only know how to write Matlab... So, I'm just trying to write and let it run but with less knowledge.

Comment: @EricBackus If I move `fft_execute(plan_forward)` (also the backward) back to the `hilbert()`, the VS will show the red saying `the variable is undefined` so where is the place better to declare these two variables?

Comment: @Kevin Leave the plan variables declared in `main`. But add them to the parameters passed to `hilbert`. So the hilbert function declaration would look like `void hilbert(const double* in, fftw_complex* out, fftw_plan plan_forward, fftw_plan plan_backward)`. Then when you call the hilbert function from main, use `hilbert(x, y, plan_forward, plan_backward);`.

Comment: @EricBackus Super cool! I got the same output answer! I think this could be my late Christmas gift, thanks! One last check, please take a look to the code that I updated to see if there are anything can be more optimized.

Comment: @Kevin See my updated answer...

Comment: @EricBackus Thanks for your advice! However, I tried to move the `fftw_destroy_plan(plan_forward);` out to the `hilbert()` and put them on the end of the `main()`(below the `displayComplex(y);`), there is a `break point` occurred, saying `CppFFTW.exe has triggered a breakpoint.` Maybe I put them on the wrong place of `main()`?

Comment: Sounds like you did the right thing, so I don't know what's causing the break point. I'm no FFTW expert though. Perhaps call fftw_cleanup() after you destroy the plans?